# Need some help with tweaking a code for woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have this code to show custom text in the categories i choose.

```
<?php if (is_product_category('furnitures')) : ?>
<p>This is the text to describe category A</p>
<?php elseif (is_product_category('kitchen')) : ?>
<p>This is the text to describe category B</p>
<?php else : ?>
<p>This is some generic text to describe all other category pages, 
I could be left blank</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

How can i make the text to also be shown in the subcategories of each parent. In the above code are "furnitures" and "kitchen" the parent and have some subcategories.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); // current term
$parent_slug = ''; // default slug param

if( $term->parent ){   // if current term has parent then get it's slug
   $parent = get_term( $term->parent, get_query_var('taxonomy') ); // term's parent
   $parent_slug = $parent->slug; // slug of parent term
}

// check current term has product_cat taxonomy
$is_product_category = '' === $parent_slug ? 0: is_product_category($term->slug);

if ( is_product_category('furnitures') || ( $is_product_category  && 'furnitures' === $parent_slug) ) : ?>
<p>This is the text to describe category A</p>
<?php elseif (is_product_category('kitchen') || ( $is_product_category && 'kitchen' === $parent_slug) ) : ?>
<p>This is the text to describe category B</p>
<?php else : ?>
<p>This is some generic text to describe all other category pages, 
I could be left blank</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/inredamo/public_html/seo-category-bottom-text/seo-category-bottom-text.php on line 11

Comment: my mistake code updated try it once

Comment: It still only shows the output for the parent category...

Comment: ok do you not want to show message on parent, only for sub category?

Comment: I would like to show the message for both parent and sub :)

Comment: code updated, i tested it on local :)

Comment: Brilliant! Now it's working. Thank you so much for giving me your time and knowledge! You really helped me a lot :-)

Comment: Would it be possible to have this code work for products as well. To have the same outputted category text shown on all products in the current category...